# What online tool could be use to keep gantt charts or similar for all team members?

Tags: process, visibility, gantt-chart

We want to keep an online gantt chart for all developers, so we can view task load.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be to host the information on your business's servers and use the [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) api; although they don't seem to offer Gantt charts as such. There are plenty of other options that, I think, approximate your feature-request.

In addition, this post specifically details how to use the Google api to create Gantt charts: [.../how-to-build-a-gantt-chart-with-the-google-charts-api/](http://www.designinginteractive.com/code/how-to-build-a-gantt-chart-with-the-google-charts-api/)

Answer (score 1):

http://freegroups.net/gantt/

http://www.helpuplan.com/

You can also look @ [dotProject.net](http://dotProject.net)